# Send Enter Key in a SSH Connector

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, ssh-keys, connector

I am trying to run some commands on a  Linux machine using a SSH connector written in Java.

I am using Jsch library to run commands via SSH.

The problem is on the end point which is Red hat Linux box :-

Once i execute a su - command 
There is a small perl program which kicks off :- Asking for some information

Something like :-

```
SHELL# su -
Enter some info
Info
Are you ok to proceed (y/n) y
SHELL#
```

I am successfully able to enter the info part from the code. But after that

Are you ok to proceed (y/n) y

MY code crashes and it looks like the y command is not taken properly.

I was wondering if i should send Y + "enter key" from the code to make it work.
How can i achieve that?

Here is the main logic of the code :-

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;


Channel channel;
Session session;

                   JSch jsch = new JSch();
                   SSHUserInfo sshUserInfo = new SSHUserInfo();
        sshUserInfo.setTrust(true);
        sshUserInfo.setPassword(loginPassword);
        sshUserInfo.setName(loginUserName);
        session = jsch.getSession(loginUserName, host, port);
        session.setUserInfo(sshUserInfo);
        session.connect();


               channel = session.openChannel(SSH_TYPE_SHELL);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        channel.connect();

               InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        channel.connect();


        out.write(("su -" + "\n").getBytes());
            out.write(("info" + "\n").getBytes());
        out.write(("y" + "\n").getBytes());
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: May I recommend you to consider using an Java expect library? Such libraries solve the problem of interacting between a Java program and a remote server or process. I'm the author of one of those. Here is the link to my GitHub project which also describes the other alternatives: https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/ExpectIt